# Is this verb usage correct? authors are recommended

Tags: verbs

For research articles of any type, authors are recommended to look at the EQUATOR network

Seems to me authors don't get recommended. Should be "we recommend that authors..." or "authors should...."

Comment: Off-topic because of incorrect parsing.

Comment: Please visit [ell.se] Good Luck.

Answer (score 4):

This form is called the **passive voice.**

In the active voice we write:

> we recommend that authors check the EQUATOR network.

Converted to the passive it becomes

> Authors are recommended to check the EQUATOR network

Comment: Good to know. I'm editing work of non-native speaker and thought it was wrong. Thanks

Comment: Typically, the subject of a passive-voice construction corresponds to the object of an active-voice construction. But "authors" is not an object in "We recommend that authors check the EQUATOR network." "Authors are recommended to check the EQUATOR network" seems like it should correspond to the active-voice sentence "We recommend authors to check the EQUATOR network"

Comment: @sumelic Good point. The passive of the mooted active should be “*It* is recommended that ...”, or more traditionally, “Authors checking the ... network *is recommended*”, though that’s starting to get unwieldy.

Answer (score 2):

transitive of ***recommend***  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/159715?rskey=FYNsOl&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> b. To advise (a person) to do a thing. Occasionally without
>   infinitive: to direct to something.

As in:

> 2000   Daily Tel. 21 July 9/1   People taking the drug **are
>   recommended to** stop and to see their doctors to discuss alternative
>   treatment.

Comment: @KannE  one can view links ... but cannot navigate the dictionary without subscription. tks